# How can I uninstall this app which keeps getting reinstalled?

Tags: applications, malware, system-apps

Hello I'm running android 4.2 Samsung rooted. There is an app which always appears on my `data/app` folder and always runs at start-up. When I go to app manager I can **uninstall** it however the next time I reboot it's still there. I cannot change its permission and I suspect it's **malware** since it's not in `system/app` folder I do not consider it a system app. 
How can I get it off my android system? **It always reinstalls during reboot**.

Comment: If you have a root access how it is even possible that you can not change it's persmissions?

Comment: I can't I even tried using the terminal

Comment: What is the app in question?

Comment: Calls itself auc.orp.bgj.apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds clearly a malware. In such case, there is always another app/scripts that reinstall it whenever you uninstall.

Download ES Explorer, open it.  Enable hidden files in its settings, also enabled root explorer.

Now navigate to the data folder, or even `/system/app` or `system/priv-app` and see if you can find some weird app names and look also for folders which names start with . (dot) and delete them.